# In app purchases iPhone simulator why disabled?

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, in-app-purchase

Just a quick question, do you see any reason why Apple has disabled many things on the iPhone simulator like:

1. testing In app purchases
2. testing most services of Game Center
3. wifi connection

How do you live with those three?

If you want to quickly debug/run your app on simulator that requires the in app purchase, do you just change some places in the source code to say the app that the purchase is done?

If you want to quicky test your application (on simulator), how it works without the Internet connection, do you turn your airport off? Do you have any ways how to check how application works when the connection is fast/slow/very slow (even on a real device)?

Regards

Answer (score 13):

It seems that Apple finally allowed testing In-App purchases in the Simulator starting from iOS 5. At least, in iOS 5 Beta 6 it worked for me.

PS. I haven't found an official proof link though...

Comment: Just confirming that this actually *does* work :) Thanks for the tip.

Comment: By the way, in IOS 6.0 they broke it again. Simulator always returns the most popular error ever created: "Cannot connect to iTunes store".

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post by [David Linsin](http://dlinsin.blogspot.com/2010/08/testing-apps-with-in-app-purchases-in.html).

From [iTunes Connect Developers Guide](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf):

> ... the Store Kit APIs are not available when testing in the iPhone simulator.

Comment: I know it does not, I'm just would like to know why don't, and if you have any workarounds.

Comment: Answer is outdated. It is now available for testing in Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Now testing in-app purchases in simulator is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Device has UDID but simulator has no UDID.

Comment: Actually, the simulator has a UDID. It's strange, but can also receive AirMail (from UrbanAirship.com) in my simulated apps.

Answer (score -1):

please Follow below link . It will Clear your doubt.

http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/.

IF you need to do in-app purchases app , You must have followings.

1. App Id (UDID) ..(provisioning)
2. iTunesConnect.
3. Create Product identifiers from iTunesConnect.
4. StoreKit frameworks.

StoreKit Framework communicate between your device and App store. Not b/w iOS Simulator and AppStore.